# how to make an icon a drop down list when clicked?

Tags: html, css

I have a canvas in which I have two icons aligned to the right.
I want that when one of the icon is clicked, a drop down menu should open containing some options.

But I don't know how to create a drop down list when the icon is clicked.so need help on this.

Comment: did you tried something...?

Comment: yeah i tried with the select tag in html...but it is creating a separate drop down and that too above the canvas and not in the canvas...can you tell me how to make it inside the canvas boundary..?
@Dinesh

Comment: Excuse me but when you say a canvas. Do you mean an html canvas element? because if so than you cannot 'put' html elements inside a canvas. You can however position them.

Comment: ok then tell me how can i position the drop down in the html canvas element ? @vabhdman

Comment: can you add a fiddle or something , that ll fetch you more answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you cannot put html elements inside a `<canvas>`, you will just have to position your html elements so that they appear to be inside the canvas.
The main trick is to wrap the `<canvas>` element inside a wrapper `<div>` like so

**EDIT** I just added an image drop-down also, heavily inspired form [Bootstrap drop-downs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns). Although it's very basic, it should work. If you want something full featured, take a look the above link ( and the whole [bootstrap fromework](http://getbootstrap.com/) is pretty good).

```js
$(".dropdown>[data-toggle='dropdown']").on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent(".dropdown").toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
#ex-canvas-wrapper{
    postion: relative;
}
#ex-canvas {
    border: 2px solid #16a085;
    background-color: #ecf0f01;
}
#canvas-select {
    position:absolute;
    left: 138px;
    top: 12px;
}
#canvas-dropdown{
  position: absolute;
  left: 145px;
  top: 35px;
}
.dropdown>.dropdown-menu{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
  min-width: 60px;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown.open>.dropdown-menu{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ex-canvas-wrapper">
    <canvas id="ex-canvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
    <select id="canvas-select">
        <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
        <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
    </select>
    <div class="dropdown" id="canvas-dropdown">
      <img data-toggle="dropdown" src="http://i59.tinypic.com/2cgdh87.png">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>Value 1</li>
        <li>Value 2</li>
        <li>Value 3</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanx a lot..it worked..but instead of this drop down list can i assign a image icon to the list which when clicked dows the same function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create dropdowns using JavaScript or using CSS.

**CSS Example**

*HTML*

```
  <ul><li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>
        Portfolio
        <ul>
          <li>Web Design</li>
          <li>Web Development</li>
          <li>Illustrations</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Blog</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
```

*CSS*

```
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

(From http://cssdeck.com/labs/another-simple-css3-dropdown-menu)

**JS Example**

Here: [Simple javascript dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362670/simple-javascript-dropdown-menu)